# show the value and for the array and where the pointers point after the following code is run

Tags: c, pointers

Here has a piece of code about updating the pointers. I am so confused about using them. Can anyone help me understand it more clearly?

```
int a[8] = {5, 7, 22, -5, 1, 13, 77, 55};
int *p, *q, i;
p = a;
q = &a[3];
//The comment is what I think for this example
*(++p) = 14;   //I don't know I should increment it first or change the
               //current pointed value. If I look at the answer, it shows 
               //pointer is increasing first which mean p points to a[1] 
               //and assign the value at a[1] to 14 
*q = (*p)++;   //After step 1, the p point to 1. Assign *p to *q and (*p)++                          
               //means value++, 14+1=15
p += 4;        //pointer increment 4
*p += 6;       //current p point to a[5] and value = value+6
*(q-3) = *p--; //*p-- means *(p--) which means pointer p move one previous
               // where a[4]. And assign 1 to  pointer q-3(location) but don't
               //change where q points to now
```

The result is a = {19
15
22
14
1
19
77
55 }
and p point to value 1 and q point to value 14.

Another example:

```
int a[] = {5, 15, 34, 54, 14, 2, 52, 72}; 
int *p = a, *q = &a[5];

*(p++) = *q – 1; //from the example above, I should say *(p++) means pointer
                 // p++ first and assign *q-1 = 1 to a[1] where p points to now but 
                 // looking at the answer, don't understand why a[0] = 1
*p = *(q-1); 
p = p + 2; 
(*p)++;
```

The result for this one is a = {1, 14, 34, 55, 14, 2, 52, 72}.

Comment: I suggest you print the whole array (on a single line) after each statement in this "chewing gum" exercise, then you can see the effect of each. `for(int i=0; i<8; i++) printf("%d ", a[i]); printf("\n");`

Comment: Pre-increment `++p` and pre-decrement `--p` will change the value of `p` before it's used. Post-increment `p++` and post-decrement `p--` will change the value of `p` after it's used.

Comment: Think of a pointer as a little arrow under the array element which is a rox of boxes. `p` starts off as an arrow pointing to the first box, `a[0]`. In `*(++p)` the `(++p)` would move the arrow to the next box `a[1]`. and the `*` says we're not looking at the arrow, we're looking at the box the arrow is pointing at. In `*(p++)`, the arrow is not moved until *after* the whole expression `*(p++) = *q - 1` is evaluated (called post-increment because it happens after the expression).